# Is SSL still secure if SSL Settings in IIS is set to ignore or accept only?

Tags: tls, iis

Is SSL still secure if SSL Settings in IIS is set to ignore or accept only?

I have setup my https and I can access it in my browser even it is set to require ssl and clientCredentialType = Certificate but I am having a problem in my mobile as I take a web reference with require ssl settings. I don't know what to do since it says http status 403: forbidden.
So is it still secure if I only set the ssl settings to accept or ignore and my web config's clientCredentialType is set to none

```
<transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
```

because this is the only way (for now) that I can access my web service

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Client certificates are not needed to keep the SSL/TLS connection secure. They are only used to authenticate the client. If your web application does not need to verify that it talks to the correct client or if it authenticates the client through other ways (like username and password) you don't need client certificates. And, since a client certificate needs to be distributed to and installed by the client first they are rarely used since they are considered too complex to handle in most situations.

Comment: so it is still okay even though others can access my web service link ? because my webservice is still secure from eavesdropping because of ssl (https)?

Comment: @jace: Protection against sniffing and man in the middle attacks is done by using the server certificate. The client certificate is not needed for this.  So yes, your service is secure against sniffing as long as the attacker has no access to the private key of your server certificate and you are using secure ciphers.

Comment: okay thanks!  such a great help for your answer. I'm already tired of finding ways how to pass the forbidden state because of client certificate. I can now take a rest since it is still secured anyway :) CHEERS!